# bash count sequential files

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm pretty new to bash scripting so some of the syntaxes may not be optimal. Please do point them out if you see one.

I have files in a directory named sequentially.

Example: prob01_01 prob01_03 prob01_07 prob02_01 prob02_03 ....

I am trying to have the script iterate through the current directory and count how many extensions each problem has. Then print the pre-extension name then count

Sample output for above would be:

prob01 3

prob02 2

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
temp=$(mktemp)
element=''
count=0
for i in *
do
   current=${i%_*}
   if [[ $current == $element ]]
   then
      let "count+=1"
   else
      echo $element $count >> temp
      element=$current
      count=1
   fi
done
echo 'heres the temp:'
cat temp
rm 'temp'
```

**The Problem:**

Current output:

prob1 3

Desired output:

prob1 3

prob2 2

The last count isn't appended because it's not seeing a different element after it

**My Guess on possible solutions:**

Have the last append occur at the end of the for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has 2 problems.
The first problem doesn't answer your question. You make a temporary file, the filename is stored in `$temp`. You should use that one, and not the file with the fixed name `temp`.
The problem is that you only write results when you see a new problem/filename. The last one will not be printed.
Fixing only these problems will result in

```
results() {
   if (( count == 0 )); then
      return
   fi
   echo $element $count >> "${temp}"
}

temp=$(mktemp)
element=''
count=0
for i in prob*
do
   current=${i%_*}
   if [[ $current == $element ]]
   then
      let "count+=1" # Better is using ((count++))
   else
      results
      element=$current
      count=1
   fi
done
results
echo 'heres the temp:'
cat "${temp}"
rm "${temp}"
```

You can do without the script with

```
ls prob* | cut -d"_" -f1 | sort | uniq -c
```

When you want the have the output displayed as given, you need one more step.

```
ls prob* | cut -d"_" -f1 | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2 " " $1}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `printf + awk` solution:

```
printf '%s\n' *_* | awk -F_ '{a[$1]++} END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}'
```

```
prob01 3
prob02 2
```

- We use `printf` to print each file that has at least one `_`
- We use `awk` to get a count of each file's first element delimited by `_` by using an associative array.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
$ ls | awk -F_ '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2 " " $1}'
prob01 3
prob02 2
```